# Retina and non-retina ios App

Tags: css, retina-display

I've got a problem with the Retina-displays. I've got a app which works fine on non-retina displays.

In my css for a list I've set the height of a `listitem` to `20px`.

Now when I try the app on a **retina-display** all the items appear **twice the size**. I guess because the iPhone 4 resolution (with `window.innerHeight` for example) is still `480x320` even if the real resolution should be `960x640`.

Now **my question is**, do I need a seperate css for the retina displays or can I scale everything?

Comment: web app. sorry forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 3):

as a web app, you will need to use the

```
-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2
```

as that's the CSS media query that will allow you to know if it is or it isn't a retina display

for a small example on a image, assuming that you have:

```html
<body class="bkground"> ... </body>
```

normally you will have something like:

```css
.bkground {
  background-image: url(my-awesome-bkg.png);
  -webkit-background-size: 32px 16px;
}
```

to load it in retina displays, you need to add:

```css
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) {
  .bkground {
    background-image: url(my-awesome-bkg-hd.png);
  }
}
```

or load all images in a external css by using:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="retina.css" 
      media="all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2)" />
```

There are external services that do this for you automatically, have a look at the awesome service provided by Sencha fellows for [Sencha.io](http://docs.sencha.com/io/1-0/#!/guide/src)

---

Link updated for Sencha.io guide documentation

> http://docs.sencha.io/0.3.2/index.html#!/guide

Comment: well yes, on images I understand that I need to get two different ones.But like I said its not about an image or anything. I've got a css for items in a list, every listitem should be 20px. And for some reason my iphone 4 thinks my resolution is 480x320, so every item in my list appears twice the size I would want it to be. I do not understand why my app thinks it has a resolution of 480x320 even if the iphone 4 could show it 960x640. I could of course create a css-class for retina and one for non-retina and differentiate but thats not really something I'd like to do.

Comment: give us a url example so we can see it and help you with... I still don't get what you are saying. I always created lists and they all display fine in any device, screen resolution and in both retina and non-retina displays... so, it would be nice to have something to look at.